# Expo fails to connect to expo servers

Tags: react-native, expo

I am behind a proxy server and `expo login` fails. I have correctly configured my proxy servers, npm works but expo does not. I have removed the expo-cli and reinstalled it about 4 times. I have removed node and reinstalled it yet, the problem persists.

```
zappy@Zap:~/Workspace/built/mobapp$ expo login

Fetching the user profile failed
Request failed with status code 400
Request failed with status code 400
Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (/home/zappy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/home/zappy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/zappy/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

zappy@Zap:~/Workspace/built/mobapp$
```

Please help me.

Comment: May be this helps: https://forums.expo.dev/t/cannnot-expo-login-request-failed-with-status-code-400/27922

Comment: ok thanks, I  will check it out.

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, did you ever find a solution to working behind a proxy?

Comment: If anyone has a solution to this problem, please share.

Comment: No, I never found a fix around this. I had to stop using a proxy in order to fix it.